# java.io.IOException is seen on kafka broker log when one of the broker shutdown forcefully

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm having fail-over setup for Kafka with 2 brokers and single zookeeper in cluster. I'm creating topics with replication factor 2 matching the number of brokers in cluster. Also, offset replication factor is set to 2 with `min.insync.replicas` value set to 1 and `acks=all`. When I'm stopping one of the brokers forcefully and starting it back, I'm getting below stacktrace on that broker console.

```
java.io.IOException: Client was shutdown before response was read
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.sendAndReceive(NetworkClientUtils.java:109)
at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.scala:107)
at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetchFromLeader(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:196)
at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:286)
at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$maybeFetch$3(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:133)
at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.$anonfun$maybeFetch$3$adapted(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:132)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.maybeFetch(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:132)
at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:114)
at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)
```

I've got one link similar to this [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/issues/799), but not sure how they are related. 
Need to know that is this known issue and ignore it or need to take care of it.

Note: Fail-over scenario works perfectly fine.

Comment: 1) Having 2 brokers and replication factor 2 is not ideal configuration. 2) What is your `unclean.leader.election.enable` set to?

Comment: Agree that it's not ideal configuration, but I'm carrying out some basic POC for fail over scenario and  `unclean.leader.election.enable` is not overridden, so set to false by default.